# AWS SDK v2 not reading AWS_PROFILE

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

My code using the SDK is:

```js
const createAwsOpensearchConnector = require('aws-opensearch-connector');

AWS.config.update({
    region: "eu-west-1"
});

const client = new OpenSearch.Client({
    node: "<node>",
    ...createAwsOpensearchConnector(new AWS.Config({
        credentials: new AWS.ChainableTemporaryCredentials({
            params: {
                RoleArn: "<ValidRoleArn>",
                RoleSessionName: 'RoleSessionName',
                DurationSeconds: 900
            },
        }),
        region: "eu-west-1"
    }))
});
```

I'm using a unix system (MacOS) so default AWS creds stored in `~/.aws/credentials` & `~/.aws/config`. I have removed the former file as I access AWS via IAM Identity Center *(SSO)*. Using the CLI SSO [wizard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/sso-configure-profile-token.html#sso-configure-profile-token-auto-sso) I have an `~/.aws/config` file that looks like:

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=testing
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=testing

[profile development]
sso_session = DevelopmentSession
sso_account_id = <sso_account_id>
sso_role_name = PowerUser
region = eu-west-1
output = json

[sso-session DevelopmentSession]
sso_start_url = <sso_start_url>
sso_region = eu-west-1
sso_registration_scopes = sso:account:access
```

I have done:

`export AWS_PROFILE=development`

& `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` nor `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are set. `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG` is set to 1. To be sure, I also set `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` to `~/.aws/config`. When I instead use AWS environment variables instead of AWS IAM Identity Center credentials like:

```bash
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN=...
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=...
```

Then it works fine. When I say that it doesn't work, I have this error thrown back:

```json
{
  message: 'Could not load credentials from ChainableTemporaryCredentials',
  errno: -65,
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '<address>',
  port: 80,
  time: 2023-06-20T21:38:44.615Z,
  originalError: {
    message: 'Could not load credentials from ChainableTemporaryCredentials',
    errno: -65,
    code: 'CredentialsError',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '<address>',
    port: 80,
    time: 2023-06-20T21:38:44.615Z,
    originalError: {
      message: 'Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1',
      errno: -65,
      code: 'CredentialsError',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '<address>',
      port: 80,
      time: 2023-06-20T21:38:44.613Z,
      originalError: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

Doing `aws sts get-caller-identity` via the CLI returns a successful response with the correct user.